# windows 7 upgrade to windows 10 different language issues

Tags: windows-7, language, windows-10-upgrade

recently, Microsoft released tool called  "MediaCreationTool" which can be used for upgrading windows 7 & 8.1 to windows 10, however, when I am using this tool, it automatically chooses Arabic language for me.

keep in mine that I have an English version of windows 7 home Premuim  Service Pack 1, unfortunately, there no option to change the language, as a result, you cant keep your programs installed on the machine.

I need to upgrade without losing any programs installed in my PC.
I have tried several times and change language and location to United Kingdom, the only thing that I can not change it is the fact that I am leaving at Kurdistan Region of Iraq.
appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the tool, where the language, has already been selected by chance?  I suspect it isn't actually selected. You could also just wait to do it through Windows Update.

Comment: I don't have a screenshot right now, but I might be able to take screenshot if I tried again, the problem with the mentioned tool is that it not giving you any option related to language, I don't understand on which base it decide Arabic interface for me, except my geographical location which I can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the upgrade tool uses language from your system locale as the installation language.

In order to change the locale, go to **Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative -> Change System Locale**. Choose the desired language there and restart your computer. After that launch the upgrade tool, and (after long re-downloading) it will propose the installation in the desired language.