# Change language completely and entirely in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, language, language-pack

I've come to a thread in this forum ([Cannot remove language pack on Windows 10 PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1323863/cannot-remove-language-pack-on-windows-10-pc/1662219#1662219)), through a link in this another thread: [Windows 10 - Cannot remove one display language](https://superuser.com/questions/1551083/windows-10-cannot-remove-one-display-language), to which I've come through a link to it forum in a Microsoft Answer question post regarding to the language change, but in Windows 10.

Before posting this question here I've also read a lot of other threads in MSDN, Microsoft Answers, Ten Forums, and so on.

Here is the thing. I've got a company laptop provided by my employer which comes with Windows 11 in English. I want it to be in Spanish, so I've installed the Spanish Language (if I've understood it straight, as from Windows 11 its correct name is LIP - Language Interface Pack) in Time and Region section inside Settings. But, unsurprisingly, several parts in File Explorer, the very same Settings app and other system areas and contextual menus remain in English.

In the Microsoft Answers thread I mentioned above, the replier suggests the original poster to uninstall completely the unwanted languages; that's how I ended up getting to these two threads in this forum.

The problem comes when I follow the steps in the #13 reply in the *Cannot remove language pack* thread: when running `lpksetup /u`, I see none additional MUI or language pack but the English one. And I wonder if this is because of having Windows 11, or because a failure or wrong action or step when installing the Spanish LIP, or because I have to install the language desired as an entire Language Pack instead of as a LIP (if so, I don't know how to do it).

Regardless, I still uninstalled the one English MUI from `lpksetup` screen, with the consequential lost of the capability of logging on to Windows because, upon restarting after the uninstallation, the Welcome screen wouldn't show up. I ended up having to use a Restore Point, and now I'm back where I started: with a hybrid-language Windows.

Hope anyone can help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Windows 10 installation language](https://superuser.com/questions/1058237/how-to-change-windows-10-installation-language)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a completely different language **permanently**  (= able to install feature updates and the inevitable repair) then the proper way to do this is to back up and install the new Windows language OS you want.

Be sure your employer agrees with this. They may also be able to assist.

Comment: Previous questions that I have attempted to diagnose enough to end of submitting a question suggest that an in-place upgrade from one region to another region won’t actually result in the language of the installation be changed. The closest you can do is change the default region of all users but ultimately if you install a British English installation, installing US English over that installation, won’t change the region of the installation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did read that suggestion in several sites among the ones I've been visiting, but I'd rather not go for that option. At least until anyone else suggests something else, if anything, to do.

Comment: You did say you wanted a permanent solution   - one that survives all feature updates and inevitable repairs